# downgrade angular 2 to angular 1.4.8

Tags: angular, migration

I have a running application in Angular 1.4.8 and now I have created some of the new requirement in  angular 4 and I need to integrate this  Angular 4 components with Angular 1.4.8 .
Is there any best way can I integrate with Angular 4 to 1.4.8

Comment: check this https://medium.com/@SevenLee/configuration-tips-to-build-hybrid-angular-1-and-angular-2-project-in-real-world-230b715629dc

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2, Angular 4, Angular 5, etc (which are similar) are considered to be a totally different project from Angular 1 (which is now called AngularJs). Migrating from Angular 2 to 4 or vice versa is not a considerable concern since they are vastly similar but migrating from Angular 1.x to 4 or vice versa is a totally different story and you would need to change a huge deal of your code especially if your controllers are huge and you weren't utilizing directives much.